# Polymer get element with conditional template

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have following template within my polymer component

```
<polymer-element name="my-element" attributes="show">
  <template if={{show}}>
     <select id="conditional-select">
     </select>
  </template>
<script>
Polymer({
    showChanged: function () {
        console.log(this.$['conditional-select']); //undefined
        setTimeout(function(){
           console.log(this.$['conditional-select']); //got it!
        },1000)
    }
})
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

Why first console output always `undefined` on show changed?
I understood, that DOM element not rendered yet within `showChanged`, but how to wait for it properly?

Comment: May i know who change the `show` attribute value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like populating `this.$` takes little bit time, so following changes in `showChanged` work for me

```
showChanged: function () {
    this.async(function() {
        console.log(this.$['conditional-select']); //undefined
        console.log(this.shadowRoot
            .querySelector('#conditional-select')); //got it!!                
    }.bind(this));
}
```